# Symfony / bundle to subdomain

Tags: dns, symfony

I have 2 bundles in my project **Web\PortalBundle** and **Web\AdminBundle**.
I want to access to **Web\AdminBundle** trough **subdomain admin.domain.com**.

I found this http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html
But I'm pretty sure, that I have to somehow modify DNS, because it's redirecting to the subdomain, that's empty.
Now I have just basic **admin.domain.com A IPv4**.

EDIT:

Or may be I should set documentroot to the same folder as main domain?
But then, it will also display the same content as main domain, am I right?

Could someone help me with it?

//Sorry, for that edit, but I don't have access to my project right, and won't be able to try it for a while.

Thanks

Comment: You can also create a separate admin environment where this bundle is loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already done this type of redirection on projects.

For DNS configuration, only a .domain.com type A pointing and a CNAME type pointing for the subdomain.

Then everything goes to the application level.

```
app_admin:
    host:     admin.domain.com
    resource: '@AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml'
```

Thanks for your feedback.